# Access all custom DOM properties

Tags: dom

How can one loop over all added DOM properties (not [browser ones](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element))?

**Example DOM:**

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div['newProp1'] = '123';
div['newProp2'] = true;
div['someOtherProp'] = false;
...
...
```

Say I don't know the names of "new" properties, how can I access them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div['newProp1'] = '123';
div.newProp2 = true;
div['someOtherProp'] = false;

for( let prop in div )
    if( div.hasOwnProperty(prop) )
         console.log( prop  );
```